# The same string twice in the $PATH environmental variable

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, grep, .profile

When I run $PATH on my terminal in Ubuntu 18.04.3, it displays the following:

`/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

The first part of $PATH (`/home/ubuntu/bin`) shows up twice. Why?

I have tried:

```
grep PATH= ~/.{bash_profile,profile,bashrc}
```

and got:

```
grep: /home/ubuntu/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
/home/ubuntu/.profile:    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
/home/ubuntu/.profile:    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
/home/ubuntu/.bashrc:export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: You likely have a line like `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` appearing in more than one of the shell's startup files (maybe both `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`)

Comment: @steeldriver, Is there a quick way to confirm that PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" is appearing more than once?

Comment: It won't be definitive (because files can source other files that can source other files...) but you could start with something like `grep PATH= ~/.{bash_profile,profile,bashrc}`. Also make sure you are not starting your shell as a login shell unnecessarily (which will re-read the bash_profile or profile).

Comment: @steeldriver, I'm not sure I understand the `~/.{bash_profile,profile,bashrc}` part of the `grep` terminal command.

Comment: `~/.{bash_profile,profile,bashrc}` is just a *brace expansion* - it expands to the 3 files `~/.bash_profile ~/.profile ~/.bashrc`. You can type them separately if you prefer.

Comment: @steeldriver, So, instead of running the grep search separately for three files, I can scan the three files at once, while the dot (`.`) before the curly bracket (`{`) is part of the file name, right?

Comment: Yes. So based on the results (and assuing that `$HOME` expands to `/home/ubuntu` i.e. that `/home/ubuntu` is set as the user's home directory), you are indeed adding it twice - once in `~/.profile` and then again in `~/.bashrc`. The second is probably superfluous. Note that the default Ubuntu `~/.profile` sources `~/.bashrc` if it exists and the shell is bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` directive from the `/home/ubuntu/.bashrc` file fixed the problem, since the `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` is already covered by `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` in the `/home/ubuntu/.profile` file.

Answer (score 0):

I use Stephen Collyer's `bash_path_funcs`, described in Linux Journal way back in 2000, but the links no longer work.

This link works today (2020-Mar-03):

http://web.archive.org/web/20061213023831/http://www.netspinner.co.uk/Resources.html

The `addpath` function adds an entry to a path only if it is not there
in the first place. `delpath -n` deletes all non-existent directories
from a path, and `uniqpath` deletes duplicate entries..
~
~